# Unable to select the drop down list while web scraping

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a website using `Excel VBA macros`. However, I am unable to select the `drop down` list with the code below:

```
Public Sub Public_Data_pulled()
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Dim html As HTMLDocument, hTable As HTMLTable

  Set html = New HTMLDocument
  
  With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/basic-select-dropdown-demo.html", False
    .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
  End With

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Set hTable = html.getElementById("select-demo")
  Title.selectedIndex = 5

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[image: Image of the drop down list]

Comment: what is the value of `hTable` after you get the element by its id?

Comment: Where did `Title` come from in the expression `Title.selectedIndex = 5` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to accomplish by performing interaction like `select` using xmlhttp.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of a code that I am using to get from a drop down list.

```
Option Explicit

Public MyElement As Selenium.WebElement

Sub Fill_Report(report As String)

    SearchFor = "select-demo"
    If Not SearchElementdByID(SearchFor) Then GoTo errHandler
    MyElement.Click
       
    ' Select
    MyElement.AsSelect.SelectByText (report)
    
    Exit Sub
    
errHandler:
    Debug.Print Now() & "; " & Err.Number&; "; " & Err.Description
    End
End Sub

Function SearchElementdByID(ByVal Search) As Boolean
    Dim FindBy As New Selenium.By
    
    Set MyElement = MyBrowser.FindElementById(Search)
    MyElement.WaitDisplayed
    
    SearchElementdByID = MyElement.IsDisplayed
End Function
```